# Error using next auth google provider with Nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm currently trying to use next-auth with the google provider and prisma with my next js app, but im getting this error:

```
Detected default export in '/MyProject/foodbrain/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.
```

Along with:

```
No HTTP methods exported in 'MyProject/foodbrain/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
```

[image: My Folder Structer]

My route.ts file:

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
});
```

I have my GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and my GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET variables set in .env.local I just don't want to put them here because they are supposed to be kept secret.

My Login.tsx file:

```
"use client";

import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end">
      <button
        className="text-black cursor-pointer underline text-lg p-6 hover:text-gray-600"
        onClick={() => signIn()}
      >
        Sign In
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

My Nav.tsx file:

```
import Login from "./Login";

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end">
      <Login />
    </nav>
  );
};
```

My Prisma schema:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                 String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?  @db.Text
  access_token       String?  @db.Text
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  @db.Text
  session_state      String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've been at this for a while and I can't seem to figure it out, and I can't find a good answer online. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @JaredSmith I saw this before and I can't seem to apply it to my problem. Thanks

Comment: You can't just export an arbitrary default function from a route handler in next 13, the documentation is very clear on this point, the error message is very clear on this point, and the stack overflow duplicate I linked as well. Your route handlers need to be named, and those names need to correspond to HTTP verbs.

Comment: If you look at the [example code](https://authjs.dev/) from next auth, they have it in the `pages` directory which does not have that restriction. Next.js uses file-based routing/policy, you can't just stick stuff wherever and expect it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by changing this:

```
export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
});
```

To this:

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app

Comment: Finally, the right answer! thank you